# Metrics on the time it takes to replciate an on-premise server to the site recovery fault

Tags: azure, migration

I'm trying to get metrics on the time it takes replicate an on premise server to ASR. I realize that this is largely due to bandwidth and size of the on-premise server instance disk etc but it would be nice to be able to get some of that data from azure of start and end time of when replication took to complete.

Is that somewhere available?
Failure I don't think is as a big of an issue it looks like Azure provides detail around that in replication jobs activity and typically doesn't seem to take more than 5 min.

Comment: *”I realize that this is largely due to bandwidth and size of the on-premise server instance disk”* - Indeed! We don’t know your numbers so how can we make a more advanced estimate?  `duration = size-of-dataset-to-be-replicated / upload-speed` where the upload-speed is not purely a function of network bandwidth but also of your disk and application load. The  size of the dataset depends on things like incremental replication of only changes (and how much that is for you) versus full transfer of a complete snapshot etc. Are you talking about MB's or GB’s?

Comment: What I  had hoped to find is metrics (from azure) when server/vm successfully replicated to Azure like the start time and end time of the initial replication. I looked in log analytics and nothing stood out.